# Calculating and storing data after each ngFor in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, calculated-columns, ngfor

I am creating a transaction tracker as a MEAN project and is stuck in here. I need to show all the transactions using ngFor. I want to show the Difference of credit and debit amount with the previous balance added to it after each transaction. Any idea how to do it?

This is my ngFor Code.

```
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let trans of transactions; index as i;">
      <td>{{ trans.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.billNo }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.creditAmt }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.debitAmt }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.debitAmt + trans.creditAmt + (DONT KNOW HOW TO ADD THE PREVIOUS BALANCE)}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

[image: The Table I am looking to achieve]

In my table now you can see, the balance is not being calculated properly.
How can I do this? How to store balance after each ngFor iteration and display it? None of my logic seems to be working.

Comment: I tried creating a variable named balanceAmount in the Typescript file and calling a method inside the ngFor balance column and adding credt and debit amount and then assigning balanceAmount to the result and returned the balanceAmount. Then I get the an error as I overwrite the balanceAmount and it gets refreshed and thus goes into an infinite loop. Error : ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Comment: I would calculate everything in an array in the class before populating the table. ..

Comment: I gave you an answer, but I agree with @Vega

Comment: I am a beginner to angular and can you give me some hints on how to do it? Should I use create a pipe? or would I be able to do in the Ts file itself?

Answer (score 1):

`<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let trans of transactions; index as i;">
      <td>{{ trans.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.billNo }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.creditAmt }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.debitAmt }}</td>
      <td>{{ trans.debitAmt +  + (DONT KNOW HOW TO ADD THE PREVIOUS BALANCE)}} </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>`

Well, you have the index. If `i != 0`..

`(trans.creditAmt - trans.debitAmt) + (transactions[i - 1].debitAmt + trasnactions[i - 1].creditAmt)`

You should do this in the component, though. As you'll need to create a variable to keep track of the previous balance, as it's also a calculation.

Comment: Wow! Never knew I can do this much calculations inside interpolation with that index i. Thank you. I am now trying something like Vega suggested, thank you for your help.